# Yosemite focus indicator animation & highlight standard behavior

Tags: macos, highlights

I'm not exactly sure how to describe this, but in Yosemite, it seems like the indicator for the currently focused field seems weird. I'm not sure whether it's a bug or intended behavior. When switching between UI elements that allow for interaction, there is some attention grabbing animation, and after the animation, the indicator seems so large that my assumption is that this is unintended. I've included some pics below

From xCode:

[image: text field Xcode]

from notification tray:

[image: Notification tray disclosure]

Is this normal behavior? If not, should I open a radar?

Comment: The thickness of the outline is actually how it looks now. I had the same reaction as you; I thought it was a bug or I had some kind of accessibility option turned on. Carrying on the tradition of iOS 7, there are a number of UI design changes in Yosemite that look like mistakes, but are actually intentional... :-/

Comment: I have this problem, too. When moving focus to a new textbox, whether with the mouse or the keyboard, there's an animated highlighting of the textbox that's a bit like a flashbulb going off. Changing the Keyboard > Shortcuts preferences didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have full keyboard access turned on. I've noticed this makes large borders around sometimes unintended controls. You can change the settings in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.
The default should be "Text boxes and lists only"

[image]

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, as it confirms that this is standard behavior in Yosemite. I also filed a radar with Apple, as I'm guessing the indicator shouldn't be touching the text in whatever UI label it is highlighting.